# Is Bootstrap all about using classes within HTML tags?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have just started using Bootstrap and found Bootstrap is only about using classes within Html tag elements. Is it correct?

Comment: have you ever looked in the source?

Comment: it has JS too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is a *front-end* framework, thus it has nothing to do with the backend. It provides common pre-defined classes which you can use, customize and extend. On the other hand it provides JavaScript (jQuery) plugins, so the answer to your question is no.

You should check their [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/), it has a lot of examples and code snippets to get started.